# Angular2 Doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-template

I'm learning Angular 2, and I've written simple app but it doesn't work as I expect. I don't know why.
So this is my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <base href="/">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Angular 2Do</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
        <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
        <script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
        <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>

        <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
        <script>
            System.import('app/main').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <list>Downloading</list>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is my main.ts (I wrote the whole code into one file to simplify structure of my message)

```
import {NgModule} from "@angular/core";
import {Component} from "@angular/core";
import {BrowserModule} from "@angular/platform-browser";
import {platformBrowserDynamic} from "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic";

class Article{
    public title:string;
    public link:string;
    constructor(title:string, link:string){
        this.title = title;
        this.link = link;
    }
}

@Component({
    selector:"redirection",
    template:`
    <li><a href="{{article.link}}">{{article.title}}</a></li>
    `,
    inputs:['article']
})
class Redirection{
    public article:Article;
}

@Component({
    selector:"list",
    template:`
    <div>
        <div>
            <ul>
            <redirection
            *ngFor="let foo of articles"
            ["article"]="foo"
            ></redirection>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <form>
        <input name="link" type="text" #newlink>
        <input name="title" type="text" #newtitle>
        <button (click)="addLink(newtitle, newlink)">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    `,
})
class List{
    public articles:Article[];
    addLink(title:HTMLInputElement, link:HTMLInputElement):boolean{
        this.articles.push(new Article(title.value, link.value));
        return false;
    }
}

@NgModule({
    declarations:[Redirection, List],
    imports:[BrowserModule],
    bootstrap:[List]
})
class Main{

}
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(Main);
```

and tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types/"
    ]
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules/*",
    "**/*-aot.ts"
  ]
}
```

This is what I've got.
[image]
And if I close `<redirection>` by the `</redirection>`, I will have parse error:

[image]
And the other error mesage, when `<redirection>` is closed
[image]

Comment: Dude, the question almost killed me:D It's almost like :"Nothing is working, wtf:D"

Comment: I understood why I have a problem. This is because of using *ngFor. But I still don't know why it's not working properlt. I suppose there's a trouble inside transpiler or inside angular depences.

Answer (score 1):

Change `<link>` to `<li></li>` and add the  selector inside of it, and try to change the selector's name because there is already a html tag with the name of `link`, change it to `linker` or what ever.
**EXP:**

```
        <div>
            <ul>
            <li *ngFor="let foo of articles">
            <linker [article]="foo" ></linker>
            </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: Thank you, I've already changed my `<link>` to `<redirection>`

Comment: I tried all what you've written and whereas I put my angular logic I have a parse error. My browser says that I don't have to close `<li>` tag with angular logic

Comment: try to delete the `<redirection></redirection>` tag and write anything instead of it (e.g: `<li>xyz</li>` )

Comment: I wrote this: `<li *ngFor="let foo of articles">abc</li>` and all work but I can't see any text in the browser, because my array is empty

Answer (score 1):

Please **close link tag** properly then after it work properly and also **li tag missing after ul**.

```
<div>
    <ul>
       <li>
            //your other tag and logic here
       </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<form>
    <input name="link" type="text" #newlink>
    <input name="title" type="text" #newtitle>
    <button (click)="addLink(newtitle, newlink)">Submit</button>
</form>
```